# SSRS - Creating distinct parameter values from SSAS OLAP cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, olap-cube

I have a list of names and email addresses (formatting below) and need to pull back only the names portion, and I need them to be in a distinct list to populate in a parameter.

### Current List

- Jane Doe (jdoe@example.com)
- Jane Doe (jsmith@another.com)
- Jane Doe (frosen@whoknows.com)
- John Smith (kmittens@santa.com)
- John Smith (wlamberson@rogerthat.com)

### Desired List

- Jane Doe
- John Smith

Since the data source is an SSAS OLAP cube I cannot write a "select distinct" query within my dataset.  Instead I am limited to using the Query Designer via a shared data source connected to the cube.

Has anyone else ever run into anything like this and found a solution?  I've been looking all over and can't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With MEMBER [Measures].[Name] 
AS
LEFT([Customer].[Customer Name].CurrentMember.Name,
InStr([Customer].[Customer Name].CurrentMember.Name,'(')-2
)
select [Measures].[Name] on columns,
DISTINCT([Customer].[Customer Name].[Customer Name]) on rows
from [Mycube]
```

It will give you a list of distinct customer names as long as customer name is composed of:

`name (email)`

Comment: Thanks for the response alejandro.

That gets it a lot closer, but not quite there.  Now the name is singled out, but it's still being repeated because it is associated with the original field "Name (email)".

Thoughts?

Comment: A name can have different mails? i.e. Jhon Smith (example1@mail.com) and Jhon Smith (example2@email.com)

Comment: exactly.  it's very odd, I know.  Been driving me crazy, haha.  However I found an alternate method just querying out of the DB that feeds the Cube, so I at least got the result I needed.  However I wouldn't hate figuring this out either :)  So any additional ideas are welcome!